# how to create a loop for dynamic dates apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I`m new to nifi and I am trying to get data from google ads api.
I need to pull data from 2021/01/01 until today.
I have a working flow that does this but the problem is that I use replace text processor as means to send json body for the gg ads api.

I want to create a loop that changes that same the dates inside that same text.

For example:

This is the text I am sending

```
{
    "query": "SELECT search_term_view.ad_group, search_term_view.resource_name, search_term_view.search_term, search_term_view.status, segments.device, segments.search_term_match_type, segments.keyword.info.match_type, segments.keyword.ad_group_criterion, ad_group.id, ad_group.name, ad_group.type, ad_group.status, campaign.id, campaign.name, campaign.status, customer.id, customer.descriptive_name, segments.keyword.info.text, metrics.clicks, metrics.cost_micros, metrics.impressions, segments.date, segments.week, segments.year FROM search_term_view WHERE segments.date >= '2021-12-16' AND segments.date <= '2021-12-31'"
}
```

The result I am looking for is some thing like this:

```
{
    "query": "SELECT search_term_view.ad_group, search_term_view.resource_name, search_term_view.search_term, search_term_view.status, segments.device, segments.search_term_match_type, segments.keyword.info.match_type, segments.keyword.ad_group_criterion, ad_group.id, ad_group.name, ad_group.type, ad_group.status, campaign.id, campaign.name, campaign.status, customer.id, customer.descriptive_name, segments.keyword.info.text, metrics.clicks, metrics.cost_micros, metrics.impressions, segments.date, segments.week, segments.year FROM search_term_view WHERE segments.date >= '$since' AND segments.date <= '$until'"
}
```

where as $since and $until are dynamic dates and use this into InvokeHTTP

${since} and ${until} is expression language - but I don`t know how to create them dynamically

This is the pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try use curved brackets, e.g. ${since} and ${until}. Also check https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#structure

Comment: I wasn`t clear enough- I don`t know how to do a loop in the first place.

${since} and ${until} is expression language - but I don`t know how to create them dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can use UpdateAttribute and RouteOnAttribute to do that:
**Generate Flow File** > **UpdateAttribute** > **Invoke HTTP** > **RouteOnAttribute** (loop condition) > **UpdateAttribute** (to increase the iterator)

- Create one or more **Generate Flow File** based on the scheduling you need
- Create an **UpdateAttribute**: with `since`  as `2021-01-01` and `until` value generated dynamically using `Now()`. Note that you can also store State so the next time the processor runs, you can resume from the stored dates/value.
  [image]

Since `since` and `until` attribute seems to meet you loop requirement in the google query, but to answer your question on how to create a loop, let's say you are looping through the `since` date

- Check `since` is less than or equal to today's date using **RouteOnAttribute** : Add a property called `OnRepeat` with the value of `${now():format("yyyyMMdd"):equals(${since:format("yyyyMMdd")})}`. At this point, you should be able create to two relationships: `OnRepeat` pointing to the next task to continue the loop (typically to increase the iterator), `unmatched` to exit the loop (or simply terminate this relationship to end the flow)
- To increate a date iterator, you can use [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) in **UpdateAttribute**: to add a day
  `${since:toNumber().add(86400000)}` with toNumber() converting the date to seconds since epoch. Create a relationship from this processor to your Invoke HTTP.

Here is a screenshot of the flows (I have not tested the solution)
[image]

Comment: Thank you- I am having a hard time configuring the settings for each processor - could you please provide the settings for each processor?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: **GenerateFlowFile** -> **SplitRecord** -> **EvaluateJsonPath**

**GenerateFlowFile**

- `CustomText`:

```json
[
  {
    "since": "2021-01-01",
    "until": "2022-01-01"
  },
  { 
    "since": "2021-07-01",
    "until": "2022-07-01"
  }
]
```

**SplitRecord**

- `RecordReader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `RecordWriter`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Records Per Split`: `1`

**EvaluateJsonPath**

- `Destination`: `flowfile-attribute`
- `since` (dynamic attribute): `$.since`
- `until` (dynamic attribute): `$.until`

Comment: Also I created a custom processor that split record to attributes [SplitRecordToAttributes](https://tonykoval.github.io/nifi-vub-scala-bundle/SplitRecordToAttributes.html)

Comment: wow! thank you so much.
So basically I create in advance the dates as json and then I can send this dynamically. 
Just super!!! Thanks you!

Comment: is there a way to make the GenerateFlowFile custom text to be auto made i.e. like in a for loop? i.e. I want the since and until to be created also auto and not to write all the dates manually