# How to run same proccesor flow with many parameters iteratively

Tags: loops, apache-nifi

I want to run a shell script to generate data files. Have created two parameters date and source. The flow is working fine with one set of parameter. But I want to run for various parameters

[image]

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71144254/3810086

Comment: use `ListenHTTP` in nifi to listen for incoming files and `curl... --data @file` to post file to the endpoint exposed by ListenHTTP.